# C# API endpoint input validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on simple API program, and I have a simple question related to endpoint input validation. This piece of code runs fine, but if I provide incorrect GUID format, it calls fallback, but I would like to get regular 400 HTTP error. Is it possible to do that with route constraints?

```
[HttpGet("/api/{context:guid}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> doSomething(Guid context) 
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "regular 400 http error"? It already returns a 400 by default. For example: if you send in the string `hello world` to that endpoint, ASP.NET Core will return 400 with JSON explaining what failed.

Comment: @Andy for some reason it redirects to "_Host" and returns code 200. I looked into docs, looks like route constraints were not intendent for input validation.

Comment: change `"/api/{context:guid}"` to `"/api/{context}"`. Just tested it and it worked fine for me.